# How can I successfully conduct a hostile stock market takeover?

Tags: railroad-tycoon, railroad-tycoon-deluxe

Whenever I buy a block of 10,000 shares in a competitor, the competitor will invariably defend itself by buying 10,000 shares as well. The competitor and I have to take turns to buy stock (because I have to call the broker for each block, and this gives the competitor time to buy a new block), so this invariably ends in a situation where I own 50% of the shares, and the competitor owns 50% of the shares as treasury stock. This means that it's not possible to conduct a stock market takeover of the competitor without making a tender offer.

What is a reliable way to get >50% of the stock without having to make a tender offer?